# cannot load such file -- mygem1

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have created mygem when i am trying to run recipe using chef-client :

```
 chef-client -zr recipe[Migration::2]
```

It's throwing error:

```
 LoadError
    ---------
    cannot load such file -- mygem

    Running handlers:
    [2018-01-02T11:57:40+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    Running handlers complete
    [2018-01-02T11:57:40+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 15 seconds
    [2018-01-02T11:57:40+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/workstation-repo/.che
    f/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    [2018-01-02T11:57:40+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace
    .out file if you file a bug report
    [2018-01-02T11:57:40+05:30] FATAL: LoadError: cannot load such file -- mygem1
```

Comment: If i run ruby file directly using ruby filename.rb it's working fine,only while running chef-client it's throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Chef uses its own Ruby environment when running, separate from the system Ruby environment. Gems can be installed via the `chef_gem` resource. This is not recommended for new users though as it is quite easy to make fragile code. If your goal is running database migrations or similar, you might want an `execute` resource running the command `'/usr/bin/ruby /path/to/migrate.rb'`.

Comment: No my goal is to create new volume using chef-client command, as i mentioned it's working if i run ruby filename.rb, i wanted to run it using chef-client(reason i have input values coming from custom node attributes)

Comment: Running it via a subprocess (i.e. `execute` resource) is fine, just make sure you use the correct ruby exectuable. That is not the same thing as `require`ing it as a gem.

Comment: execute 'crate_vol' do
 command 'C:\workstation-repo\cookbooks\Migration\recipes\2.rb'
 action :run
end
Do you mean by this way ?

Comment: You would need the copy the script to the node (possibly using a `cookbook_file` resource and you need something like `c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe` in there so it runs under the correct Ruby environment, but something like that.